# Is there any way to have postgresql translate select * column names into fully qualified table.column_name form?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query something like this:

```
select * from table1, table2, table3;
```

but I need column names to be unique in the result set.

I tried:

```
select table1.*, table2.*, table3.* from table1, table2, table3;
```

but this doesn't result in fully qualified column names.

Is there a way to ensure that column names are fully qualified in the result set?

Like this:

```
table1.id
```

instead of:

```
id
```

without using aliases, i.e. the AS clause.

Comment: use column `alias`es.

Comment: When you use `table1.id`, the name is `id`.  If you want the full name, use `table1.id as "table1.id"`, but that seems awkward.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll clarify the question. I know about aliases. I would like the system to expand the fully qualified column name since it clearly knows the table names. I could also do this with a SQL metaprogramming sub-select but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Many people want to be able to say `select * except x, y, ...`. But I don't know of any platforms that have any kind of expansion features like this or for the one you're asking about.

Comment: The client-side can know the underlying table corresponding to a column in a resultset through `PQftable()`. But that's the OID of the table, not its name. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQFTABLE

Comment: @DanielVérité You can then map that to the table and column names via information_schema though.

Comment: ... or get the table name via `SELECT 123::regclass`, where "123" is the table OID. That's how I did it for HeidiSQL.